# Add parameter entered to pull report to PDF file name

Tags: vba, ms-access, office365

In the small section of coding the DoCmd command creates a PDF of a report "VRRrep222". I enter the "VRR#" that I need to create. After this an e-mail is created and sent.

In `filename =` the name of the PDF will be "VRRrep222" and today's date. I need the VRR# that I entered to pull the report to also be the number in the file name (and also the subject line in my code which I did not paste here).

Is there a way to associate the report # being pulled so that it can be added to the PDF name and subject line without having to manually enter it?

```
Sub SendEmail()
Dim filename As String, todaydate As String
Dim Msg As Object
Dim Supplier As String

Supplier = InputBox("Supplier E-mail?")
todaydate = Format(Date, "MMDDYYYY")
filename = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\VRRrep222_" & todaydate & ".pdf"
DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "VRRrep222", acFormatPDF, filename, False
Set Msg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    With Msg
           Msg.To = Supplier
           Msg.From = ""
           Msg.cc = ""
           Msg.bcc = ""
           Msg.Subject = ""
           Msg.TextBody = "This is an automated email that is being sent as an ALERT only. If the disposition is RETURN TO VENDOR, you will be notified with another email."
           Msg.addattachment filename
           Msg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
           Msg.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = ""
           Msg.Configuration.Fields.Update
           Msg.Send
    End With
Kill filename

Set Msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm new to VBA as of yesterday.

Comment: Where are you entering the VRR#? Is it a prompt from Access?

Comment: @K753 The VRR# is prompted when the code is ran.

Comment: @K753 I actually think I'm missing something here. I'm actually removing the original email macro. If I go to the report in Access Objects and try and open it ask me "what vrr# would you like to e-mail?" Sorry I'm new to VBA and don't study much coding apparently I need to.

Comment: That number should come directly from the DB without the user entering it. You should be displaying DB entries to the user. The user selects an entry and then clicks the button to run the export.

Comment: You're using that `With` statement wrong. Please read this:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement

Comment: And then read this: https://blogs.starcio.com/2013/04/please-stop-creating-microsoft-access.html

Comment: @HackSlash I'm not sure about the "with" part it was copied over from another part of the script that was given to me. I just made adjustments that were necessary to get the e-mail output which works just fine. I'm trying to fine tune the rest so that it is easier to find if the user needs to go back and find it in their e-mail by getting the VRR# put in the PDF name and Subject line.

Comment: @lamar249 It sounds like there is a parameter in the query for the report. If you look through the query or queries that the report is based on you might see a field with the bracketed prompt in the criteria. That would be the field that's capturing the VRR# and you can then reference that in your code. It could also be a message box prompt that's capturing the number too.

Comment: @K753 I just now looked at your comment. I just finished looking and found the table that the VRR# is being pulled from. Is there a way that I can reference the Parameter entered during the first prompt in the code so it doesn't have to be typed again to add to subject line or in the PDF name? if so could you possibly put a code here that I can copy?

Comment: @K753 Found the query that it is associated with and in design view the row labeled "criteria" the first and only column has anything in it has "Like [Enter VRR# To Email].

Comment: @lamar249 Without seeing more of the query structure and what's being done with that I value I can't provide any code examples right now. There are probably multiple ways to store that value in a variable. It might be easier to pull it from the report field.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling value from report data would require report be open first. Current code doesn't do that.

Don't use dynamic parameterized query with popup prompt. Query popup inputs are poor design because input cannot be validated and cannot be referenced for other purpose, such as your requirement. Use a control on form for input of criteria parameter. Either have query parameter reference form control or apply filter to report with OpenReport method. Then code can reference that control to build file name and subject. Perhaps a combobox would be best then users can only select valid VRR#.

```
filename = Application.CurrentProject.Path & "\" & Me.cbxVRR & "_" & todaydate & ".pdf"
DoCmd.OpenReport "VRRrep222", acViewPreview, , "YOURfieldname=" & Me.cbxVRR, acHidden 
DoCmd.OutputTo acReport, "VRRrep222", acFormatPDF, filename, False
DoCmd.Close acReport, "VRRrep222", acSaveNo
...
    .Subject = Me.cbxVRR
```

I never use dynamic parameters in query.

Comment: I'm not the one who created this DB as it was made years ago. I just started in IT and only been here for 3 months. I Have a lot to learn especially when it comes to this even though this is dated. I'll have to look at this next week before I can get back to you on this. The help is much appreciated.